# Difference between JPA generation Strategy TABLE and SEQUENCE

Tags: jpa, sequence

I am using Spring boot with MySql and Hibernate. I have simple application where i have User table.

```
@Entity(name = "user")
Public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int Id;
    // Getters Setters and remaining attributes
```

Then I am inserting 20 records in user table with Spring Transaction

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) 
 userService.save(new User("fName"+i, "lName"+i);
```

I can see following output for all 20 insert queries

```
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
Hibernate: insert into user (fname, lname, id) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
Hibernate: insert into user (fname, lname, id) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
Hibernate: insert into user (fname, lname, id) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
Hibernate: insert into user (fname, lname, id) values (?, ?, ?)
```

As per my understanding of GenerationType.SEQUENCE, it should only query once from the DB and after that hibernate should not query next Sequence from DATABASE and keep on generating Sequences until it reaches next allocationSize (50 by default). Why it is always querying database for all the IDs. 
In my opinion this behaviour should reflect with GenertaionType.TABLE (which is happening if i change it)

Comment: take a look at the following article https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-replace-the-table-identifier-generator-with-either-sequence-or-identity-in-a-portable-way/

Comment: I believe this behavior is quite normal. In this case you have a single sequence in the database. In order to assign new id, hibernate needs to call next_val from the sequence in the database every time. hibernate_sequence is your single point of new ids.

Comment: Which version of MySQL? Do you specify an Hibernate dialect?

Comment: I was under the impression that the `SEQUENCE` generation type only worked on PostgreSQL and Oracle.

Comment: @Teodor Dinitrov, but my understanding is even if you use single table it should not query DB for creating all the IDs

Answer (score 0):

To avoid hits to database you should use pooled-lo optimization strategy.

Also, when using MySQL database, there is not much of a difference between generation Strategy TABLE and SEQUENCE. Since MySQL does not supports sequences, both of these strategies create an underlying table to maintain a primary key counter, mentioned [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators-sequence) and [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators-table).

The only difference is that TABLE generator maintains the primary key next_val counter in the same underlying table for multiple entities vs. the SEQUENCE generator stores next_val in separate tables, also found a [performance comparison here](https://www.truiton.com/2024/02/spring-boot-hibernate-jpa-generationtype-table-vs-sequence-strategy-with-mysql/).